Forbidden error when creating a CloudDNS managed zone
I have a service account with following roles:
roles/dns.admin
roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageAdmin

I'm using it to create a CloudDNS managed zone using Terraform:
resource "google_dns_managed_zone" "my_zone" {
  name        = "my-zone"
  dns_name    = "mydomain.com."
  description = "My zone"
}

I'm using JSON key authentication (environment variable GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEYFILE_JSON pointing to the JSON service account's key)
I get this error:

Error: Error creating ManagedZone: googleapi: Error 403: Forbidden, forbidden

Am I missing any permission? I have double checked and everything seems okay.
CloudDNS API is enabled.

I suspect you're not setting the environment variable correctly. Where are you running this? How are you using GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEYFILE_JSON exactly? You can verify that the Service Account has roles/dns.admin which is sufficient to create the zone by gcloud auth activate-service-account and running gcloud dns managed-zone-create while authenticated as it.

Do you manage other resources with terraform ? does these resources added by terraform with the same configuration ?
Do you want to create a public or private dns zone ?

I think the required role is roles/dns.admin as seen in this documentation
